# Программное оформление html кода

Tags: html, c++

Программно получаю строки (c++, std::string) с неоформленным html кодом, можно ли как-то строки программно обрабатывать и придавать html коду оформление, т.е. расставлять отступы и переносы на новую строку?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно проходить по всем html тегам и каждому дочернему тегу добавлять табуляцию `'предыдущее кол-во табуляций' + 'еще одна'`.
Вам нужно будет определять когда тег открывается и когда тег закрывается.

Comment: Ещё нужно переводы на новую строку ведь как-то делать, т.к. весь код идёт одной строкой, самому всё это разрабатывать довольно не просто, неужели нету уже готового решения?

Comment: Ну можно добавлять символ перевода строки в то место когда открывается новый тег - `'\n'` и будет вам перевод на новую строку.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо и на этом, как я понимаю всё это делать регулярными выражениями?

Comment: @nammidd, по этому поводу есть очень эмоциональный и развернутый [ответ на so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, это не совсем решение вашей задачи, но поищите в boost::property_tree. Возможно для ваших целей подойдёт запись и xml.

Например, записать из неоформленного простенького html-файла оформленный xml можно вот так:

```
boost::property_tree::ptree tree;
boost::property_tree::read_xml("DirtyFile.txt", tree);   
boost::property_tree::write_xml("PrettyFile.xml", tree, std::locale(), boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::string>(' ', 4));
```

В результате из файла вида

```
<html><head>some</head></html>
```

вы получите

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
    <head>some</head>
</html>
```

Конечно, ещё необходимо избавиться от версии xml в заголовке, но это несложно.

**EDIT**

Исходные данные из строки

```
std::string in_raw = "<html><head>lala</head></html>";
std::istringstream in_stream(in_raw);
boost::property_tree::ptree tree;
boost::property_tree::read_xml(in_stream, tree);
```